the state of a boolean variable is not resetting in setState
My server is returning a paginated list of transactions and I am using bloc to manage my state. I have isMoreLoading that is resetting to false after the loaded state of my bloc finished executing. Then I have a method that loads the next url of my transaction request and this method checks and be sure that isMoreLoading is false before executing else it won't execute. I tried to print out some stuffs as shown in the comment of my fetchMoreTransData and discovered that isMoreLoading is true while the method was called even when I reset it to false after my loaded and error state finished execution. Because of this issue, the fetchMoreTransData wasn't triggered in the addListener of the scrollview because the method can only be triggered if isMoreLoading is false. Please I need help on how to resolve the issue of isMoreLoading still returning true after loaded state finished execution.
class _PageTransactionsHistoryState extends State<PageTransactionsHistory>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController animationController;
  final refreshController = RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);

  final ScrollController _scrollController =
  ScrollController();

  final homeBloc = sl<HomeBloc>();
  List<Transaction> transactions = [];
  List<Transaction> filteredTransactions = [];
  bool isLoading = true;
  String errorText = '';

  //more loading
  bool isMoreLoading = false;
  //errorState
  bool inErrorState = false;

  int currentCount = 0;
  int pageCount = 20;
  int currentStartPosition = 0;
  int currentEndPosition = 20;
  bool hasMore = false;
  String? nextUrl;
  String? path;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    );

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      //call the fetch more function
       fetchMoreTransData();
      
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    refreshController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => homeBloc..add(GetTransactionsEvent()),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: AppColor.kColor700),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          centerTitle: false,
          titleTextStyle: context.toolBarTitleStyle,
          title: const Text('Transactions'),
        ),
        backgroundColor: AppColor.kGhostWhite,
        body: SafeArea(
          bottom: false,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: BlocListener<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
              listener: (context, state) {
                if (state is GetTransactionsLoading) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (transactions.isEmpty) {
                      isLoading = true;
                    } else {
                      isMoreLoading = true;
                    }
                    inErrorState = false;
                  });
                } else if (state is GetTransactionsLoaded) {
                  refreshController.refreshCompleted();
                  final transMetaData = state.transactionMetaModel;

                  setState(() {
                    isMoreLoading = false;
                    if (!filteredCall) {
                      transactions.clear(); // Clear previous transactions
                      transactions.addAll(transMetaData.transactions);
                    }
                    isLoading = false;
                    inErrorState = false;
                    currentCount = transMetaData.totalPage!;
                    pageCount = transMetaData.perPage!;
                    hasMore = transMetaData.canLoadMore;
                    nextUrl = transMetaData.nextPageUrl;
                    path = transMetaData.path;
                    currentEndPosition = min(
                      transMetaData.totalPage!,
                      currentEndPosition + transMetaData.currentPage!,
                    );
                  });
                  pp('The next url is $nextUrl');
                  pp('Can load more is $hasMore');
                  pp('The path is $path');
                  pp('The page count is $pageCount');
                } else if (state is GetTransactionsError) {
                  refreshController.refreshCompleted();
                  setState(() {
                    errorText = state.failure.message;
                    if (transactions.isEmpty) {
                      inErrorState = true;
                      isLoading = false;
                      isMoreLoading = false;
                    } else {
                      isMoreLoading = false;
                    }
                  });
},
              child: SmartRefresher(
                controller: refreshController,
                enablePullDown: true,
                onRefresh: () {
                  homeBloc.add(GetTransactionsEvent());
                  setState(() {
                    transactions.clear();
                    filteredTransactions.clear();
                    filteredCall = false;
                  });
                },
                child: transactions.isEmpty
                    ? isLoading
                        ? Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              bottom: size.height * 0.2,
                            ),
                            child: const CPayLoadingIndicator(),
                          )
                        : errorText.isEmptyOrNull
                            ? const EmptyListWidget(
                                backgroundColor: AppColor.kGhostWhite,
                                icon: Icons.free_cancellation_outlined,
                                text: 'No transactions',
                              )
                            : const EmptyListWidget(
                                icon: Icons.error,
                                text:
                                    'Cannot load transactions.\nTry refreshing your screen',
                              )
                    : filteredTransactions.isEmpty && filteredCall?
                const EmptyListWidget(
                  backgroundColor: AppColor.kGhostWhite,
                  icon: Icons.free_cancellation_outlined,
                  text: 'No transaction found\nRefresh screen for all transactions',
                )
                    :CustomScrollView(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    if(filteredTransactions.isEmpty) ...[
                      ...transactions.mapTransactions.values
                          .map(
                            (e) => BlocProvider(
                          create: (context) => sl<HomeBloc>(),
                          child: TransactionStickyCard(
                            onDatesSelected: _onDatesSelected,
                            transactions: e,
                            onPressed: () {},
                            onFilterClick: () {
                              filterTransaction();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                          .toList()
                    ]else ...[
                      ...filteredTransactions.mapTransactions.values
                          .map(
                            (e) => BlocProvider(
                          create: (context) => sl<HomeBloc>(),
                          child: TransactionStickyCard(
                            onDatesSelected: _onDatesSelected,
                            transactions: e,
                            onPressed: () {},
                            onFilterClick: () {
                              filterTransaction();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                          .toList()
                    ]
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  void fetchMoreTransData() {
    pp('Fetch more called');
    final triggerFetchMoreSize =
        0.75 * _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;

    if (_scrollController.position.pixels >= triggerFetchMoreSize) {
      pp('First step');
      pp('Has more here is $hasMore');//printed true
      pp('Is the current end position less than current count ${currentEndPosition <=currentCount}');//printed true
      pp('Not is more loading ${!isMoreLoading}');//printed false
      pp('Not in error state ${!inErrorState}');//printed true


      if (hasMore &&
         currentEndPosition <= currentCount &&
         !isMoreLoading &&
         !inErrorState) {
        pp('second step');
        setState(
              () {
                pp('Inside fetch more');
            isMoreLoading = true;
            currentStartPosition = currentEndPosition;
            currentEndPosition =
                min(currentStartPosition + pageCount, currentCount);
          },
        );
        //call get transaction event with next url
        homeBloc.add(GetTransactionsEvent(nextUrl: nextUrl));
        pp("Scroll position: ${_scrollController.position.pixels}");
        pp("Max scroll extent: ${_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent}");
        pp("Trigger fetch more size: $triggerFetchMoreSize");
      }
    }
  }



The aboved code is what I have tried but still not working
